# How To Extract Numbers from a String without regex

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, guava

I want to extract `Number`s from a string, example message is like this

> Hello Your Account NO 295093491783 is been deducted by 17820.if you did not receive the Ack call 9897123456.

Right now i am using Google's Guava Like this

```
String temp = CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.retainFrom(message);
```

for which I am getting the result like ***295093491783178209897123456*** and my desired format is

```
String[] a = {"295093491783", "17820", "9897123456"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I Wanted to do this using the guava library.

***Note***:-

1. I don't want to use regex because `CharMatcher` is faster than regex.
2. My current solution is almost running at ***6000 tps*** (Transactions Per Second).

Comment: How many of these do you have to process per second?

Comment: right now my solution is almost running at 6000 TPS(Transactions Per Second)

Comment: @PrakharNigam were you able to benchmark the regex and matcher solutions?

Comment: @nullpointer yet not benchmarked ... still to go on

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:

```
static String[] getNumbers(String from) {
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < from.length(); i++) {
        char c = from.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            number.append(c);
        } else if (number.length() > 0){
            numbers.add(number.toString());
            number.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    if (number.length() > 0) {
        numbers.add(number.toString());
    }
    return numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
}
```

But have you actually benchmarked the regex solution?

Comment: No-till now i haven't benchmarked the RegEx solution.

Comment: @PrakharNigam let me know the results, seems like micro-optimizaton to not use regex since your input is so tiny.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki actually this is a single fragment of a message. my actual message can be of multi-part with a minimum of as such 3 fragments and maximum up to 256  fragments. i am comparing both the solutions i will share the scores for both soon